# Perfect Usage of "Never"

Tags: grammar

While I was reading a quiz, I found the following choice question:
She never (do - does - did) her homework at school.

Since my native language is not English and I am still in the very beginning way to studying English, I found that "never" can be used in Present Simple Tense as well as Past Simple Tense and other tenses, but I am still unsure whether this one can be a multiple choice question or there is a matter of preference here. I really couldn't make my mind up.

Could you, please, help, friends?

Thanks in Advance,
Yusuf Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good multiple choice question should have at least one wrong answer. The wrong one here is *'Do'*. The sentence there would be: She does not *do* her homework at school. A different form of never rather than does. The other choices could be used for tenses you mention.

Comment: I'd have said *good multiple choice question should have **exactly one right** answer*. Unless associated instructions made it clear the task was to identify the ***one and only*** "wrong" answer.

Comment: Just finished a test where there were as many as three right answers. Instructions were painful. Multiple choice tests mean the teacher has failed to serve their function.